# Print alternate elements in the list (raising IndexError: list index out of range)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop, slice

How do I print every other item in a list without it giving me this error?

Im confused, I have tried this a million times in a million different ways, but same answer.
My code right now:

```
item = 0
fruit = ['Strawberry','apple','pear','orange','banana','cucumber','tomato','Kiwi']
for count in fruit:
    print(fruit[item])
    item = item + 2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

You may use slicing feature of list, i.e. you may slice your list content as:

```
your_list[start:end:step]
```

which in simple words will create a new list:

- starting from index `start`
- upto index `end`
- with step of `step`

For more information, read: [Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/2063361)

In your case, you can iterate over the sliced list with step of 2. You do not need index as a pointer to your list as your `for` will do it for you. Your code will look like this:

```
>>> fruit = ['Strawberry','apple','pear','orange','banana','cucumber','tomato','Kiwi']
>>>
>>> for f in fruit[::2]:
...     print f
...
Strawberry
pear
banana
tomato
```

Here `fruit[::2]` holds the value:

```
['Strawberry', 'pear', 'banana', 'tomato']
```

---

**Edit**: Reason for the failure of your code is, you are iterating over the entire list let's say of *n* length. But you are accessing the item at the *twice* the index of your current position. When you will be on *n/2* th element, you will try to access item as *fruit[n]*, which will raise `IndexError` as your list was holding item only upto *n-1* th index.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to iterate over `fruit` by skipping every 2 elements, you may proceed like below:

```
for item in fruit[::2]:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code doesn't work is because

```
for count in fruit:
```

iterates over each item in the `fruit` list, so once you're at the half-way point, `item` will point beyond the end of the list. Here's a modified version of your code to illustrate:

```
item = 0
fruit = ['Strawberry', 'apple', 'pear', 'orange', 'banana', 'cucumber', 'tomato', 'Kiwi']
print(len(fruit))
for v in fruit:
    print(v, item)
    item = item + 2
```

**output**

```
8
Strawberry 0
apple 2
pear 4
orange 6
banana 8
cucumber 10
tomato 12
Kiwi 14
```

So once we reach "banana", `fruit[item]` will try to access an item beyond the end of `fruit`, and that raises an `IndexError` exception.

---

As others have mentioned, the usual way to do this task in Python is to use extended slicing:

```
fruit = ['Strawberry', 'apple', 'pear', 'orange', 'banana', 'cucumber', 'tomato', 'Kiwi']

for v in fruit[::2]:
    print(v)
```

**output**

```
Strawberry
pear
banana
tomato
```

If you want the odd items, you can start the slice at 1:

```
for v in fruit[1::2]:
    print(v)
```

**output**

```
apple
orange
cucumber
Kiwi
```

Or you can just print a slice, as is, since it's just a list:

```
print(fruit[::2])
```

**output**

```
['Strawberry', 'pear', 'banana', 'tomato']
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a slight mistake in your code in the print statment:

```
item = 0
fruit = ['Strawberry','apple','pear','orange','banana','cucumber','tomato','Kiwi']
for item in fruit[0::2]:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
Strawberry
pear
banana
tomato
```